# Lie algebra structure constants

Tags: representation-theory, mathematics, lie-algebra, linear-algebra

A lie algebra  $\mathfrak{g}$ is a vector space together with a composition law $[.,.]$ that stratifies some properties (bilinear, Jacobi, etc).
Since it's a vector space you can chose a basis $X_1,...,X_n$, which are called generators, and you get the structure constants $c_{jkl}$ as follow:

$$[X_j, X_k] = c_{jkl}X_l$$

My understanding is that the structure constants depends on the chosen basis for the Lie algebra vector space (see B.C Hall "Lie Group, Lie Algebras, and Representations pag. 52).

Is my understanding correct?

A Lie algebra representations on a vector space $V$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism (i.e. preserve the composition law), defined as follow:

$$\pi: \mathfrak{g} \to End(V), \,\, \pi(X) = \mathscr L_{X}$$

where $End(V)$ is the space of liner map $\mathscr L: V \to V$ (see see B.C Hall "Lie Group, Lie Algebras, and Representations pag. 77).
If we chose a basis in the vector space $V$ the linear map $\mathscr L$ can be represented by a matrix:

$$\pi: \mathfrak{g} \to \mathscr M(V), \,\, \pi(X) = M_X$$

If we chose a different basis in the vector spaces $V$ we have different matrix but from the linear algebra we know the following relation:

$$M^{\prime}_X = SM_XS^{-1}$$

Thanks to that relation we can see that the structure constants doesn't depends on the chosen basis for the vector space $V$:

$$[M^{\prime}_{X_j},M^{\prime}_{X_k}] = [SM_{X_j}S^{-1}, SM_{X_k}S^{-1}] = S[M_{X_j},M_{X_k}]S^{-1} = c_{jkl}SM_{X_l}S^{-1} = c_{jkl} M^{\prime}_{X_l}$$

Those two statements about the structure constants do not contradict each other, cause the first one is about the Lie algebra as a vector space, and the second one about the vector space used to represents the Lie algebra with matrix, which are different vector spaces.

Now, consider the generator of the rotation Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so(3)}$, in physics book the structure constants are usually the following:

$$[J_j, J_k] = i\epsilon_{jkl}J_l$$

I can rescale the generators with -1 factor and I get different structure constants

$$J^{\prime}_i = -J_i$$

$$[J^{\prime}_j, J^{\prime}_k] = - i\epsilon_{jkl}J^{\prime}_l$$

My understanding is that those are still valid generators for the the rotation Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so(3)}$, though the structure constants are different.

Is my understanding correct?

The underlying reason of my questions is that, by reading the Zee book on group theory for physicist, I got the message that algebra structure constants are import in physics cause they "uniquely" define the Lie algebra and then also the underlying physics concepts based on that algebra.
However, since same Lie algebra can have different structure constants, it seems that message is not that correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.